# Find a nonzero matrix $A$ in $M_{2\times 2}(R)$ satisfying $v\cdot Av=0$ for every $v\in R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Ok, so I have this problem: Find a nonzero matrix $A$ in $M_{2\times 2}(R)$ satisfying $v\cdot Av=0$ for every $v \in R^2$.

So if I say that $v=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$ and that $A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$  so that $A*v=\begin{bmatrix}ax+by\\cx+dy\end{bmatrix}$.  So I'm pretty sure that Im being asked to find $a,b,c,d$ such that $v \cdot Av=x(ax+by)+y(cx+dy)=0$

Now, since it has to be a nonzero matrix would it make sense to make the values opposites of each other so that they cancel out?? If not, can someone help in what to do?

Comment: Remember that this should work for EVERY x and y, so try plugging in values of x and y to see what you can conclude about a,b,c,d.

Comment: I added the "\$" signs to your $\LaTeX$ so it would render properly.  And a couple of periods.  Hope this is OK with you; if not, feel free to change it back!

Answer (score 2):

Since your result has to hold for every $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$. So try the following three vectors:
$$v_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}, \quad v_2=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}, \quad v_3=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$

You will get sufficient information about the matrix $A$.

For example
$$v_1 \cdot (Av_1)=v_1 \cdot \left(\begin{bmatrix}a &b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}\right)=v_1 \cdot \begin{bmatrix}a\\c\end{bmatrix}=a(1)+c(0)=a.$$

Comment: so for v_1, i got ax+cy, for v_2 I got bx+dy and for V_3 I got a+b+c+d My knowledge is not very developed of this subject but I'm not seeing how this helps me.

Comment: there should be no $x$ and $y$. With my choice of $v_1$ your $x=1$ and $y=0$. I have elaborated a bit more in the solution.

Comment: First result is a, second is d, third is column matrix, [a+b, c+d]

Comment: How can the third result be a column matrix? It should be a scalar like the others.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the requirement $v \cdot Av = 0$, $\forall v \in \Bbb R^2$ carefully you will soon realize that it forces the matrix $A$ to be skew-symmetric, that is, $A^T = -A$.  This follows from a standard argument, for we may write

$(v_1 + v_2) \cdot A(v_1 + v_2) = 0 \tag{1}$

for any $v_1, v_2 \in \Bbb R^2$.  Then

$v_1 \cdot Av_1 + v_1 \cdot Av_2 + v_2 \cdot Av_1 + v_2 \cdot A v_2 = 0, \tag{2}$

and since $v_i \cdot Av_i = 0$ for $i = 1, 2$ we have

$v_1 \cdot Av_2 + v_2 \cdot Av_1 = 0. \tag{3}$

(3) yields

$v_1 \cdot Av_2 = - v_2 \cdot Av_1 = -A^Tv_2 \cdot v_1 = - v_1 \cdot A^Tv_2, \tag{4}$

showing that $A^T = -A$.  It is easy to see then that $A^T = -A$ implies $a = -a$, $d = -d$, $c = -b$, so we must have $a = d = 0$ but $b$ may be chosen freely.  If one is not acquainted with the formula $v_1 \cdot B v_2 = B^Tv_1 \cdot v_2$ used in (4), one may simply choose

$v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \tag{5}$

and

$v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \tag{6}$

and explicitly evaluate (3) together with $v_i \cdot Av_i = 0$, $i = 1, 2$, to obtain the same result.  It is easy to see that with

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & b \\ -b & 0 \end{bmatrix} \tag{7}$

that $v \cdot Av = 0$ holds for all $v \in \Bbb R^2$.

***Note:*** The relation $A^T = -A$ follows from $v \cdot Av = $ for $A \in M_{n \times n}(\Bbb R)$, we don't need $n = 2$ to obtain this result.  ***End of Note.***

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***